# Cannot get value when working with struct in c

Tags: c, struct

I am writing a program which prompt user to enter information of cities (in the program I test with 2 cities: `city a, b`) then print out these value. Each city has 4 value: `name`, `income`, `population` and `literarte_rate`. The problem is when I enter information `literrate_rate`, it automatically print out `0.000000` and save it to variable. I am still able to enter value to it and the next infomation.

**Input**

```
city name: qwerty 123 !@#
income: 789
population: 123456
literation: 0.000000685
city name: asdfgh 456 $%^
income: 456
population: 999999
literation: 0.00000065684
```

**Output**

```
city name: qwerty 123 !@#
income: 789
population: 123456
literation: 0.00
city name: asdfgh 456 $%^
income: 456
population: 999999
literation: 0.00
```

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct City
{
    char name[51];
    double income;
    unsigned int population;
    double literate_rate;
}city;

void input(city *tmp);
void output(city tmp);

int main(){
    city a, b;
    input(&a);
    input(&b);
    
    output(a);
    output(b);

    return 0;
}

void input(city *tmp){

    printf("city name: ");
    fgets(tmp->name, 50, stdin);
    tmp->name[strlen(tmp->name)-1]='\0';
    
    printf("income: ");
    scanf("%lf", &tmp->income);
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    
    printf("population: ");
    scanf("%d", &tmp->population);
    while(getchar()!='\n');

    printf("literation: ");
    printf("%lf", &tmp->literate_rate);
    while(getchar()!='\n');

}

void output(city tmp){
    printf("\ncity name: %s", tmp.name);
    printf("\nincome: %.2f", tmp.income);
    printf("\npopulation: %d", tmp.population);
    printf("\nliteration: %.2f", tmp.literate_rate);
}
```

I have tried to use `while(getchar()!='\n');` after each `scanf` with number but it does not solve the problem.

So how to fix it and make more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In input function, you are not scanning the value of literate_rate, you are printing its address instead.

Comment: You read `literation` using `printf`. Doesn't your compiler give you a warning about this line, since I think it's standard in all modern C compilers to check the type of printf arguments when the format string is present as a literal string.

Comment: Omg, how can I miss this bug, thanks both of you.@kiner_shah and @Paul Hankin

Comment: @PaulHankin I don't see any error from compiler, could you show me how to turn on the warning. I am using gcc 6.3.0

Comment: During compilation something like: `gcc -Wall filename.c -o outputfilename`

Comment: @kiner_shah do I still need `-g` in arguments?

Comment: I don't know what is the complete command you use, but to see warnings use `-Wall` option.

Comment: Looks like ubuntu enables format checking by default, but in standard gcc it's not enabled. `gcc -Wformat` enables this, but as others have suggested, `gcc -Wall` is recommended which enables this warning and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the call to *scanf*:

```
printf("%lf", &tmp->literate_rate);
```

should be

```
scanf("%lf", &tmp->literate_rate);
```

Also, you should check the result of scanf (which returns the number of scanned tokens) to make sure the scan was successful.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice, thank you so much.